# Does the browser re-render the whole page on changes or only the specific elements?

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance, browser

Assume I have an element with id `#msg` and on a certain condition I want to add to it a class in order to apply a style e.g. to make the text appear red.
I can do `$('#msg').addClass(theclass)`
My question is how does the browser react? Does it re-render all of the page or does it re-render that specific element?

Comment: The answer depends on the browser, the version (maybe the platform), the css changes implied by the new class, the css of the ancestor nodes and nodes around the element. For example, if you want to do some optimizations for Chrome, you can have a look at _layout boundaries_.

Comment: @Volune:I find it hard to believe that this is not specified.From my point of view this affects performance of a page dramatically.

Comment: I don't understand how you go from _re-render affects performance dramatically_ to _re-render has to be specified_. The display of the page is specified. If you change a class, the specifications tell you what the display will be after the change. You can then identify what need to be re-rendered. The default algorithm for that would be to redraw all the page then compare with previous display. Browsers' developers are still making better and better algorithms to find what need to be re-rendered without redrawing all the page.

Comment: @Jim was this issue resolved? Unanswered posts slow things down when users looking for help read these posts, please select a post as an answer or revisit and update this thread.

Answer (score 13):

With your example (`addClass`), it depends what is in the class you add. Adding of the class itself only modifies the attribute on the targeted node.

- Some changes will cause a  **repaint**, that is when changing the color, bgcolor, etc. Only the elements to which the new CSS is applied, will be re-rendered.
- Some changes will cause a **reflow**, that is when the **visible** space occupied by elements or their contents change dimensions or position. Depending on their own, & their parent's & children's properties, and those's parent's & children's properties, and so on, and so on, the reflow will affect more elements in the document tree.

Browsers are smart enough to only modify the elements that require re-rendering. A technique to minimize the amount of re-renders is to set the element's `position: absolute` or `display: none` to remove it temporarily from the document flow, make your changes, then re-insert. This is especially important if, eg. you make some element slide down. If the element is in the flow & at the beginning of the DOM tree, every pixel it stretches will cause a re-render.

For the sake of fun, let's make a simple analogy with paper on a desk, in this example with element insertion. The desk is your browser window, `□` = paper, `_` = empty space. You want to put another sheet at the top left-most position. This is the start-situation:

`□ □ □ □`
`□ □ □ □`
`_ _ _ _`

After you put your new sheet on the desk: (■ = new, ▧ = moved)

`■ □ □ □`
`▧ □ □ □`
`▧ _ _ _`

If the second row was one long roll of paper though (= a full-width div), the entire row would move:

`■ □ □ □`
`▧ _ _ _`
`▧▧▧▧▧▧▧`

If you inserted the sheet on the third row however, no reflow would occur.

**Note:** This is the theoretical explanation. Its efficiency will vary per browser.
**Source:** High Performance Javascript, 'Repaints & reflows', p.70.

Answer (score 5):

My understanding, based on the results presented by this tool https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/timeline is that **NO**, the entire DOM is not repainted/regenerated, just the element that had the class change.

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/dcyevpwe/)

HTML:

```
<p>Lorem ipsum dolar sit amet...</p>

<input id="btn" type="button" value="click me" />
```

Javascript:

```
$(document).on('click', '#btn', function () { 
  $('p').addClass('red')  
})
```

CSS:

```
.red {
    color: red;
}
```

****edit****
I had to change my answer from No to Yes, then back to No from Yes. This tool clearly points to the element in question being repainted, the other DOM elements aren't affected.

**However**
If the element inner/outer dimension is changed, or even needs to be queried by the javascript, this will require the DOM element to be redrawn and the entire elements branch will be redrawn then cached by the browser.

[image]

Comment: Try with inline elements to see that other elements may need the be redraw, for example: `<span>A</span><span id="putAClassThatChangeTheFontSize">B</span><span>C</span>`

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is it depends, as browsers are smart enough to find out when to perform a whole rendering, and when to render only the affected parts. To answer your question, I will briefly describe the rendering process, and will focus more on layout (reflow) and painting, as answering your question involves understanding how those 2 steps are performed.

## 1. The rendering process

When the `HTML` page is received by the browser, it is parsed so that the output of this parsing is called `DOM` tree (Document Object Model), which has the `Document` object as root, and other corresponding html elements. This parsing is done in order to provide a representation that can be used by the external world (javascript for example).

Then, the `CSS` files will parsed and the output is what is called `Render` tree, which contains only visible elements (elements with display property as none will not be present in the render tree)as they are supposed to be displayed. Each element in the DOM tree has a corresponding element in the render tree, for example, a `<div>` has `Block` as corresponding element in the render tree.

After that, style computation is performed in order to calculate the final styles of how the elements should look like on the screen. Once the style computation is done, layout happens, followed by painting.

Layout (or reflow) consists of calculating the coordinates and placing elements on the browser window.

Painting consists of displaying elements on the screen.

All renderers (the web page elements) have a `layout` (or `reflow`) method, each renderer invokes the layout method of its children that needs layout.

[image: The rendering process]

If you want more details how parsing, style computation, and how browsers work, you can check out [this link](https://web.dev/articles/howbrowserswork)

## 2. How is the layout performed?

The layout can be done either **globally** or **incrementally**.

### Global Layout

it is usually triggered synchronously on the entire render tree, i.e the whole tree is laid, and it can be due to the following:

- A global style change that affects all the rendering tree (Eg: a
  change in the font size)
- The screen being resized

### Incremental Layout

In order to avoid updating the entire render tree, browsers use a `dirty bit system`, i.e when a renderer needs a change in the layout, it updates the dirty bit to true, and when the change is done, it updates the dirty bit to false. There are two flags: `dirty`, and `children are dirty`, which means even if the parent is ok, at least when of its children is dirty(needs an update in layout). It is usually triggered asynchronously to update only "dirty" elements. Example, when new renderers are appended to the render tree after extra content came from the network and was added to the DOM tree (Eg, clicking on a button "Show more" which loads more data and add them to the DOM), only the concerned element and its descendants will be updated.

**Asynchronous** Incremental layouts in Firefox are queued and a scheduler batches their execution, a listener-based approach is used to detect updates on the DOM. On the other hand, WebKit (the rendering engine in Safari) has as a timer that periodically checks for dirty renderers through traversing the render tree, and executes an incremental layout.

Incremental layout may be triggered **synchronously** in some cases that require realtime data such as `offsetHeight` which provides real-time information about an element's dimensions. When scripts request such information, the browser must ensure that it is accurate, which may involve triggering an incremental layout update).

It is worth noting that sometimes layout is triggered as a callback after an initial layout because some attributes, like the scrolling position changed. For example, if you scroll down a long web page, the browser needs to adjust the position of elements to reflect the new viewport (visible area of the browser window). To do this efficiently, it doesn't recalculate the layout for the entire page but focuses on the elements that have moved into or out of the viewport.This approach is an optimization technique to minimize the performance impact of layout changes caused by user interactions, ensuring that the web page remains responsive and provides a smooth user experience.

### The Layout process

The layout has the following process:

1. The parent renderer determines its own width
2. The parent goes through its children and :

   - Places the child renderer (sets its coordinates x and y)
   - For each child, the layout process might involve calculating the child’s height. This calculation can be triggered due to several reasons such as a change in the child’s dimensions (due to content update for instance), or during a global layout update.
3. Once all children have been placed and any layout calculations are done, the parent renderer calculates its own height, which is determined by the heights of its children, including any paddings and margins. This height will also be used by the parent render’s parent …
4. After completing the layout of all children, the parent marks itself as not dirty, and sets the dirty bit to false, which indicates that the layout is up to date.

## 3. How is Painting performed?

The render tree is traversed, and the `paint()` method of the renderer is called to display the content on the screen.

Similarly to layout, painting can be global or incremental.

### Global Painting

The entire tree is painted.

### Incremental Painting

Only some of the renderers change in a way that does not change the entire tree. The render that changes, invalidates its rectangle on the screen and marks itself as **dirty**, and generates a **paint event**.  The browsers do it in a clever way by gathering several regions into a single batch in order to minimise the overhead of repainting and ensure that the process is as efficient as possible.

Hope this gives a clue on cases when incremental or global layout is triggered.

Answer (score -2):

The Critical Rendering Path is the sequence of steps the browser goes through to convert the HTML, CSS, and JavaScript into pixels on the screen. Optimizing the critical render path improves render performance.